# If statement inside chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

How do I use if statement inside chef recipe?

I want to clone repository only if folder doesn't exists or even better clone it if it doesn't exists and pull if it does

I have a code:

```
bash 'clone-mercurial-repository' do
    if !File.exist?("/root/projects/some_repo")
        code <<-EOH
            cd '/root/projects/'
            hg clone https://bitbucket.org/some_repo
        EOH
    end
end
```

This code gets executed not matter what, I also tried putting `not if` at the end but it also didn't work..

Regards, Blake

Answer (score 6):

You can use `only_if` and `not_if` to control execution of any resource (including the bash resource).

For example:

```
bash 'clone-mercurial-repository' do
    code <<-EOH
        cd '/root/projects/'
        hg clone https://bitbucket.org/some_repo
    EOH
    not_if { File.exist?("/root/projects/some_repo") }
end
```

Unrelated to your problem, you might want to check out the [mercurial cookbook](https://github.com/poise/mercurial) to avoid using the bash resource.